# How to wrap a react node by another node inside a react component

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am using owl-react-carousel in my react app. owl carousel injects some div after component render. I want to create a div using react-dom and then want to wrap owl carousel's injected div. trying to make more clear

```
 class Items extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <div className="item"></div>
      )
  }
}
```

after render this component owl carouse injects some node inside item class. Like bellow

```
<div className="item">
    <div className="owl-nav"></div>
</div>
```

Now i want to create my own div and then want to wrap owl-nav div

expected : want to create new node `<div className="custom-nav"></div>`
component should look like

```
<div className="item"> 
        <div className="custom-nav">
           <div className="owl-nav"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could made it like be

```
componentDidMount() {
const appNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
var searchingElement = appNode.querySelector("div.owl-nav");
  var wrapperElement = document.createElement("div");
  wrapperElement.setAttribute("class", "custom-nav");
  searchingElement.parentNode.insertBefore(
    wrapperElement,
    searchingElement
  );
  wrapperElement.appendChild(searchingElement);
}
```

It meets my requirement but i dont want to use document direct in react so tried react.createElement but then it says wrapper is not a node